# How to make responsive menu with php?

Tags: php, menu, responsive

I'm new with php, so this is very basic question.

What I want to do, is change my current old school menu to responsive one. 
What is the easiest way to do it? 
Now my menu contains 5 buttons, each button links to another subsite. 
But I'd like to have 1 fixed page with only content changing and menu adapting. 
I made it sound complicated but I don't know how to explain it otherwise.

Thank you

Comment: PHP doesn't know how to be "responsive", HTML/CSS do. Just do as you normally would and apply php directives as needed.

Comment: Learn HTML and CSS to work with that. PHP is a programming language, not for design. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ajax for this purpose.. Because ajax can load a particular area of a webpage without loading the whole webpage.

When you apply ajax your menubar remains as it is but the page below menubar will be loaded by ajax.

Comment: This is what I want, yes. To load particular area of a webpage. Guess I'll have to look into ajax. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look into AJAX, sorry am on Ipad

Comment: why would they need ajax for having responsive pages?

Comment: It sounds to me like he is looking to dynamically change his menu options? Not about making the menu itself responsive? I think it's a poor choice of words but he is looking to change his menu items on the fly as far as I can tell and possibly updating the page content as well? Sorry if I have misunderstood!